# Lay out items in a given space with relative sizes based on fill factors

Tags: algorithm, rust

I need to lay out one-dimensional items in a given space. The items have a given starting size. They can stretch to fill the available space but never shrink. Each item has an associated fill factor that is used to determine the ideal size relative to the other items. Items with a fill factor of 0 always keep their original size.

If the starting sizes and the available space make it impossible to allocate the space in such a way that the ideal relative sizes are achieved, then I want to allocate the extra space to the items such that the new relative sizes are closest to the optimal values. I'm not set on a specific measure of "closest" but allocating more space to an element with a relative space that's already larger than it's relative fill factor is not what I want.

I wrote an implementation in Rust that allocates the extra available space according to the relative fill factor but that only works correctly in the case where there is enough available space to achieve the optimal size ratio. When that's not the case it fails because it always allocates some extra space to every item with a positive fill factor.

Here's my code along with some test cases that hopefully demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

```rust
fn allocate_space(
    current_sizes: &[f32],
    fill_factors: &[u16],
    available_space: f32,
) -> Vec<f32> {
    // Assumptions
    {
        assert_eq!(current_sizes.len(), fill_factors.len());
        assert!(current_sizes.iter().sum::<f32>() <= available_space);
    }

    // Implementation
    let mut sizes = Vec::from(current_sizes);
    let fill_factor_sum = fill_factors.iter().sum::<u16>();

    // I'll probably need this
    let _fixed_size = current_sizes
        .iter()
        .zip(fill_factors)
        .filter_map(|(space, fill_factor)| {
            (*fill_factor == 0u16).then_some(space)
        })
        .sum::<f32>();

    if fill_factor_sum > 0 {
        let extra_space = available_space - sizes.iter().sum::<f32>();
        for (space, fill_factor) in sizes.iter_mut().zip(fill_factors) {
            *space += f32::from(*fill_factor) / f32::from(fill_factor_sum)
                * extra_space;
        }
    }

    // Constraints on the result
    {
        for ((current_size, new_size), fill_factor) in
            current_sizes.iter().zip(&sizes).zip(fill_factors)
        {
            // The allocated space is not allowed to shrink
            assert!(new_size >= current_size);
            // Items with a fill factor of zero keep their original size
            if *fill_factor == 0u16 {
                assert_eq!(current_size, new_size);
            }
        }
        // Can't use more space than available
        assert!(sizes.iter().sum::<f32>() <= available_space);
    }

    sizes.into()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn enough_space_for_relative_fill_factors() {
        assert_eq!(allocate_space(&[1.0, 1.0], &[1, 1], 4.0), vec![2.0, 2.0]);
        assert_eq!(allocate_space(&[1.0, 1.0], &[1, 1], 5.0), vec![2.5, 2.5]);
    }

    #[test]
    fn not_enough_space_for_relative_fill_factors() {
        assert_eq!(allocate_space(&[1.0, 2.0], &[1, 1], 3.5), vec![1.5, 2.0]);
    }

    #[test]
    fn unequal_fill_factors() {
        assert_eq!(allocate_space(&[1.0, 1.0], &[1, 2], 3.0), vec![1.0, 2.0]);
        assert_eq!(allocate_space(&[1.0, 1.0], &[1, 2], 2.5), vec![1.0, 1.5]);
    }

    #[test]
    fn fixed_spaces() {
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(&[1.0, 2.0, 2.0], &[0, 1, 1], 7.0),
            vec![1.0, 3.0, 3.0]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(&[1.0, 2.0, 2.0], &[0, 1, 2], 6.0),
            vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn three_variable_sizes() {
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(&[1.0, 1.0, 2.0], &[1, 2, 1], 4.0),
            vec![1.0, 1.0, 2.0]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(&[1.0, 1.0, 2.0], &[1, 2, 1], 6.0),
            vec![1.0 + 1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 + 2.0 / 3.0, 2.0]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(&[1.0, 1.0, 2.0], &[1, 2, 1], 7.0),
            vec![1.0 + 2.0 / 3.0, 3.0 + 1.0 / 3.0, 2.0]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(&[1.0, 1.0, 2.0], &[1, 2, 1], 8.0),
            vec![2.0, 4.0, 2.0]
        );
    }
}
```

My gut feeling is that there's a relatively simple solution to this problem but I can't quite figure it out.

I provided Rust code as an example because I'm using this for a Rust program but I'd be happy with help in any language, pseudo code, math or text.

**EDIT**
Here's my implementation of @btilly's answer, using the `float-cmp` crate to check the `f32`s for approximate equality.

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
struct Item {
    size: f32,
    fill_factor: u16,
}

impl Item {
    fn size_over_fill(&self) -> f32 {
        self.size / self.fill_factor as f32
    }
}

fn item(size: f32, fill_factor: u16) -> Item {
    Item { size, fill_factor }
}

fn allocate_space(items: Vec<Item>, available_space: f32) -> Vec<f32> {
    assert!(
        items.iter().map(|i| i.size).sum::<f32>() <= available_space,
        "Sum of current sizes is smaller than total available space"
    );

    // Implementation
    let mut fill_factor_sum = items.iter().map(|i| i.fill_factor).sum::<u16>();
    let fixed_space = items
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|i| (i.fill_factor == 0).then_some(i.size))
        .sum::<f32>();
    let mut size_sum = available_space;

    let sorted_items = sort_items(items.clone());

    let mut new_sizes = sorted_items
        .iter()
        .map(|(i, item)| {
            let fill_size =
                item.fill_factor as f32 / fill_factor_sum as f32 * size_sum;
            let new_size = if item.size < fill_size {
                fill_size
            } else {
                item.size
            };
            size_sum -= new_size;
            fill_factor_sum -= item.fill_factor;
            (i, new_size)
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    // Sort the elements back into original order
    new_sizes.sort_by(|(a, _), (b, _)| a.cmp(&b));

    // Constraints on the result
    for ((_, new_size), Item { size, fill_factor }) in
        new_sizes.iter().zip(&items)
    {
        assert!(
            new_size >= size,
            "Allocated space must not be smaller than the starting size"
        );
        if *fill_factor == 0u16 {
            assert_eq!(
                new_size, size,
                "Items with a fill factor of zero must keep their original
                size. Original size: {}, new size: {}",
                size, new_size
            );
        }
    }
    assert!(
        new_sizes.iter().map(|i| i.1).sum::<f32>() == available_space,
        "Should use all available space. Space used: {}, available_space: {}",
        new_sizes.iter().map(|i| i.1).sum::<f32>(),
        available_space
    );

    new_sizes.into_iter().map(|(_, size)| size).collect()
}

fn sort_items(items: Vec<Item>) -> Vec<(usize, Item)> {
    let mut items = items.into_iter().enumerate().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    items.sort_by(|a, b| {
        if a.1.fill_factor == 0 {
            return Ordering::Less;
        } else if b.1.fill_factor == 0 {
            return Ordering::Greater;
        }

        b.1.size_over_fill().total_cmp(&a.1.size_over_fill())
    });
    items
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use float_cmp::assert_approx_eq;

    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn sort_correctly() {
        let item_a = item(1., 1);
        let item_b = item(1., 0);

        assert_eq!(
            sort_items(vec![item_a, item_b]),
            vec![(1, item_b), (0, item_a)]
        );

        let item_a = item(1., 1);
        let item_b = item(1., 0);
        let item_c = item(2., 1);
        let item_d = item(2., 3);
        assert_eq!(
            sort_items(vec![item_a, item_b, item_c, item_d]),
            vec![(1, item_b), (2, item_c), (0, item_a), (3, item_d)]
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn enough_space_for_relative_fill_factors() {
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(1., 1)], 2.),
            vec![1., 1.]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(1., 1)], 4.),
            vec![2., 2.]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(1., 1)], 5.),
            vec![2.5, 2.5]
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn not_enough_space_for_relative_fill_factors() {
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(2., 1)], 3.5),
            vec![1.5, 2.]
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn unequal_fill_factors() {
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(1., 2)], 2.5),
            vec![1., 1.5]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(1., 2)], 3.),
            vec![1., 2.]
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn fixed_spaces() {
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(vec![item(1., 0), item(2., 1), item(2., 1)], 7.),
            vec![1., 3., 3.]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            allocate_space(vec![item(1., 0), item(2., 1), item(2., 2)], 7.),
            vec![1., 2., 4.]
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn three_variable_sizes() {
        assert_approx_eq!(
            &[f32],
            &allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(1., 2), item(2., 1)], 4.),
            &[1., 1., 2.]
        );
        assert_approx_eq!(
            &[f32],
            &allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(1., 2), item(2., 1)], 4.5),
            &[1., 1.5, 2.]
        );
        assert_approx_eq!(
            &[f32],
            &allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(1., 2), item(2., 1)], 5.),
            &[1., 2., 2.]
        );
        assert_approx_eq!(
            &[f32],
            &allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(1., 2), item(2., 1)], 6.),
            &[4. / 3., 8. / 3., 2.]
        );
        assert_approx_eq!(
            &[f32],
            &allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(1., 2), item(2., 1)], 7.),
            &[5. / 3., 10. / 3., 2.]
        );
        assert_approx_eq!(
            &[f32],
            &allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(1., 2), item(2., 1)], 8.),
            &[2., 4., 2.]
        );
        assert_approx_eq!(
            &[f32],
            &allocate_space(vec![item(1., 1), item(1., 2), item(2., 0)], 7.),
            &[5. / 3., 10. / 3., 2.]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends on the starting sizes of the two elements and their fill factors. Say it starts `1, 1` with fill factors `2, 5`, then the end values are `10/7, 25/7` because it's possible to get the 2 to 5 ratio with these starting values. If the starting values are `2, 1`, the solution is `2, 3` because that's best you can do with those starting values.

Comment: Your tests should probably not test for equality as that's really fragile for floating points especially ones like `2.0/3.0` which cannot be represented as an exact value. See [Is floating point math broken? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: That's a fair point but these tests are only to verify the behavior. I can visually confirm if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorganize them so that the ones with a 0 fill factor are first, and the rest have `space / fill` in descending order. Then in pseudocode

```
total_space = available_space
total_fill = sum(fill for items)
for item in items:
    fill_space = total_space * (item.fill / total_fill)
    if item.space < fill_space:
        item.space_used = fill_space
        total_space -= fill_space
        total_fill -= item.fill
    else:
        item.space_used = item.space
        total_space -= item.space
        total_fill -= item.fill
```

What this will do is assign each item its space until you only have items left that can be assigned proportions that are relative to each other.

Comment: I updated my question with an implementation of this algorithm. It looks like it doesn't always allocate all the available space.

Comment: In some cases it uses more than the available space.

Comment: @avs My bad. The `total_space` should be thought of as `total_space_still_available` and so should be initialized to `available_space`. It should only use more than available space if there is an additional bug, or you're passed items whose required space sums up to more than what is actually available.

Comment: One example where it fails: take two items with size 1 and 2. Both have fill factor 1 and the total available space is 3.5. The correct allocation then is [1.5, 2]. With the algorithm you proposed the first item has a `fill_space` of 1.75 which is larger than the starting value so it gets allocated that 1.75. But that violates the constraints because the total allocated space is now 3.75.

Comment: @avs Dang it. I wrote that just before a nap and was sloppy. I got the sort backwards, now fixed. The purpose of the sort is to look at the size 2 object first, allocate it (we have to assign it 2), and then all of the space is assigned by relative size to the other item.

Comment: now it works. Thanks! I've updated my question with my implementation.